# Spring boot createJarFileFromFileEntry

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot app and I start it with -Dloader.path=. One of the jar files is hive-exec.jar. This has a jar file bundled called minlog-1.2.jar. If I specify this file in -Dloader.path, I get an error,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'minlog-1.2.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:355)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:341)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getClassPathArchives(PropertiesLauncher.java:445)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:564)

However, if I copy this file into a folder and add that folder in -Dloader.path, I don't get any error.

What am I missing?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to manage the database driver as external jar instead of a project's maven's dependency. The application use the JPA framework, and we wanted to be able to switch from one SQL-database implementation from one environment to another (for example, H2 in DEV, Oracle in production). I had to manage the h2-database-driver jar as an external dependency. While loading it with the "-Dloader.path" command line option, I came accross he same problem as you described.

Viewing the org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile source code, the class manage an folder-entry and a jar-entry differently.
The method getNestedArchives seems to invoke the createJarFileFromFileEntry method which throw this exception. 
There must be a good reason for it, if someone know about it, any comment is welcomed!

When loading jar dependencies from a directory, the java.util.jar.JarFile constructor is used instead and does not seem to throw any exception...

In the createJarFileFromFileEntry method, instad of throwing an exception, wouldn't it be possible to only have a log.warn and not throw an exception?

Comment: As far as i know to use loader.path one needs to use 'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher' instead of jar launcher. I am using it but it still fails with same exception. I am guessing underneath it uses Jar launcher. how about opening a bug for this?

Comment: I am also using 'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher'. For me, it is just a bit weird that we have different behaviours by importing a jar by giving the directory containing it and giving the jar itself. I will follow your recomandation and will opened the following issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3701